# Were Egyptians, as a large group, slaves in Abram's time & does this have anything to do with the iniquity of the Amorites?

Tags: hebrews

*NASB95 for reference*
**Genesis 16:1**
Hagar is the Egyptian handmaid/slave of Abram & Sarai.
**Genesis 15:16**
God tells Abram his descendants will be enslaved for 400 years because of the iniquity of the Amorites.

Are the Hebrews enslaved by Egyptians in part because the iniquity of the Amorites was that Abram's people were Egyptian slave owners?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  hanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Hagar was Egyptian is not germane to this question.  However, the Amorite probation is another matter entirely.  [The Egyptians at this point in history had not been enslaved by anyone.]

The comment from Ellicott is helpful in his remarks about Gen 15:16.

> The iniquity of the Amorites.—As the chief and leading tribe, they are
> used here for all the Canaanite nations.

One of the best summaries of the purpose of Gen 15:16 is given by Benson:

> Genesis 15:16. They shall come hither again — Hither to the land of
> Canaan, wherein thou now art. The reason why they must not have the
> land of promise in possession till the fourth generation, is, because
> “the iniquity of the Amorites was not yet full.” The righteous God has
> determined that they shall not be cut off till they are arrived to
> such a pitch of wickedness; and therefore, till it come to that, the
> seed of Abram must be kept out of possession.